# How to generate a parent-child "tree" view of all component imports in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module

Is there a way to generate a "tree" view of all components in a React application? For example, if I have the following simple application file structure:

```
src/
  - index.tsx
  - App.tsx
  - components/
    - ComponentOne.tsx
    - ComponentTwo.tsx
```

And my `index.tsx` file looks something like this:

```
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app-root"));
```

And my `App.tsx` file looks something like this:

```
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne";
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo";

export default function App(){
  return (
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />
  );
}
```

Is there a way to generate a map of this structure in a JSON format, something like this?:

```
{
  "index.tsx": {
    "filepath": "...",
    "imports": {
      "App.tsx": {
        "filepath": "...",
        "imports": {
          "ComponentOne": { ... },
          "ComponentTwo": { ... }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I assume the compiler must create something similar to this format through the course of compiling the application (i.e. parsing import statements, determining child-parent relationships), and there's obviously various factors affecting how module paths are resolved, but being able to programatically generate even a simple representation (like the one shown in the Chrome React developer console) would be extremely helpful for my project.

Comment: You can use webpack to output graph information of the module imports, which you can visualize using online tools. See [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/690).